# Returning a stream from a Spring REST Controller

Tags: java, spring

I am curios if it is possible to return a `Stream` from a Spring `RestController`

```
@RestController
public class X {
  @RequestMapping(...)
  public Stream<?> getAll() { ... }
}
```

Is it ok to do something like this? I tried and Spring returns something else other than the values of a stream.

Shall I keep returning a `List<?>`?

Comment: List is the better way

Comment: Why is it better?

Comment: I do not know how the return value Looks like if you return a stream. But what if the Client do not know anything about streams like java7?!

Comment: @tzortzik because List or Set can be more useful for determining a lot of things. See the discussion [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28164852/returning-stream-rather-than-list).

Comment: I wouldn't bet money on the question, whether JSON or whatever you use for serialization, is capable of handling a stream. Streams are not serializable by default. Could be possible, the stream is linked to a non-serialized underlying data structure, which is not returned.

Comment: @Jens If it's a REST controller than the client doesn't need any dependencies, if by REST, OP means a general API that provides some endpoints.

Comment: @px06 You are right. But Client must be able to deserialize the stream

Comment: @Jens That's right and as mentioned above, the issue of deserialization makes it a bad choice to use `Stream` for a REST endpoint that a client will use.

Comment: There is a nice post on the matter [here](https://www.airpair.com/java/posts/spring-streams-memory-efficiency) and also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28830096/stream-closeable-resource-with-spring-mvc. I'm not sure if support for streams has been added to Spring 5 (or if it is only in the reactive part of Spring 5).

Answer (score 16):

This can also be accomplished with Spring MVC Controller, but there are a few concerns: limitations in Spring Data JPA Repository, whether the database supports Holdable Cursors (ResultSet Holdability) and the version of Jackson.

The key concept, I struggled to appreciate, is that a Java 8 Stream returns a series of functions which execute in a *terminal operation*, and therefore the database has to be accessible in the context executing the terminal operation.

**Spring Data JPA Limitations**

I found the Spring Data JPA documentation does not provide enough detail for Java 8 Streams. It looks like you can simply declare `Stream<MyObject> readAll()`, but I needed to annotate the method with `@Query` to make it work. I was also not able to use a JPA criteria API `Specification`. So I had to settle for a hard-coded query like:

```
@Query("select mo from MyObject mo where mo.foo.id in :fooIds")
Stream<MyObject> readAllByFooIn(@Param("fooIds") Long[] fooIds);
```

**Holdable Cursor**

If you have a database supporting Holdable Cursors, the result set is accessible after the transaction is committed. This is important since we typically annotate our `@Service` class methods with `@Transactional`, so if your database supports holdable cursors the `ResultSet` can be accessed after the service method returns, i.e. in the `@Controller` method. If the database does not support holdable cursors, e.g. MySQL, you'll need to add the `@Transaction` annotation to the controller's `@RequestMapping` method.

So now the ResultSet is accessible outside the `@Service` method, right? That again depends on holdability. For MySQL, it's only accessible within the `@Transactional` method, so the following will work (though defeats the whole purpose of using Java 8 Streams):

```
@Transaction @RequestMapping(...)
public List<MyObject> getAll() {
   try(Stream<MyObject> stream = service.streamAll) {
        return stream.collect(Collectors.toList())
    };
}
```

but not

```
@Transaction @RequestMapping
public Stream<MyObject> getAll() {
    return service.streamAll;
}
```

because the *terminal operator* is **not** in your `@Controller` it happens in Spring after the controller method returns.

**Serializing a stream to JSON without Holdable Cursor support**

To serialize the stream to JSON without a holdable cursor, add `HttpServletResponse response` to the controller method, get the output stream and use `ObjectMapper` to write the stream. With FasterXML 3.x, you can call `ObjectMapper().writeValue(writer, stream)`, but with 2.8.x you have to use the stream's iterator:

```
@RequestMapping(...)
@Transactional
public void getAll(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    try(final Stream<MyObject> stream = service.streamAll()) {
        final Writer writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(response.getOutputStream()));
        new ObjectMapper().writerFor(Iterator.class).writeValue(writer, stream.iterator());
    }
}
```

**Next steps**

My next steps are to attempt refactor this within a `Callable` `WebAsyncTask` and to move the JSON serialization into a service.

**References**

- Be sure to read Marko Topolnik's blog post https://www.airpair.com/java/posts/spring-streams-memory-efficiency, without which I wouldn't have known where to start.
- MySQL >5.0.2 now supports cursors, so you can add `useCursorFetch=true` to the connection string -- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html
- FasterXml serialization of Java 8 Stream -- https://stackoverflow.com/a/37979665/2562746

Comment: This is a fantastic answer explaining the nuances of dealing with streams and transactional JPA dbs.  It's a shame spring can't handle this case natively.

Answer (score 13):

You can stream entities in **Spring 5.0 / WebFlux**.

Take a look at this example **REACTIVE Rest Controller** (`spring.main.web-application-type: "REACTIVE"`):

```
@RestController
public class XService {

    class XDto{
        final int x;
        public XDto(int x) {this.x = x;}
    }

    Stream<XDto> produceX(){
        return IntStream.range(1,10).mapToObj(i -> {
            System.out.println("produce "+i);
            try {Thread.sleep(1000);} catch (InterruptedException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
            return new XDto(i);
        });
    }

    // stream of Server-Sent Events (SSE)
    @GetMapping(value = "/api/x/sse", 
    produces = MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE)
    public Flux<XDto> getXSse() {
        return Flux.fromStream(produceX());
    }

    // stream of JSON lines
    @GetMapping(value = "/api/x/json-stream", 
    produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_STREAM_JSON_VALUE)
    public Flux<XDto> getAllJsonStream() {
        return Flux.fromStream(produceX());
    }

    // same as List<XDto> - blocking JSON list
    @GetMapping(value = "/api/x/json-list", 
    produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public Flux<XDto> getAll() {
        return Flux.fromStream(produceX());
    }
}
```

[Spring Framework 5.0 - WebFlux:](https://spring.io/blog/2017/02/23/spring-framework-5-0-m5-update)

> Spring’s reactive stack web framework, new in 5.0, is fully reactive and non-blocking. It is suitable for event-loop style processing with a small number of threads.

[Server-Sent Events (SSE):](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-sent_events)

> Server-sent events is a standard describing how servers can initiate data transmission towards clients once an initial client connection has been established.

[WebSockets vs. Server-Sent events/EventSource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5195452/websockets-vs-server-sent-events-eventsource)

Comment: I tried your code, but ran into this problem:

`Failed to send ...$XDto
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No suitable converter for class ...$XDto`

What am I missing?

Comment: @platzhersh check this one:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37841373/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-no-converter-found-for-return-value-of-type
add getter, setter then you are good