# Stream result set using Spring Data from a Spring Batch Tasklet

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, java-stream, spring-batch

I am wanting to stream some data out the database after a Spring Batch Tasklet step

```
public class TaskletUpdateAll implements Tasklet {
    @Autowired
    private AdRepository adRepository;

    @Override
    public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution sc, ChunkContext cc) {

        return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
    }

    @AfterStep
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public ExitStatus afterStepMethod(StepExecution stepExecution) {
        try (Stream<Pair<String, String>> adStream = adRepository.streamAll();) {
            adStream.forEach((Pair ad) -> {
                // Process ad 
            });
        }
        return ExitStatus.COMPLETED;
    }
}
```

Despite the fact the method that calls the stream is annotated with `@Transactional(readOnly = true)` it still returns the following error message:

> Caused by: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException:
>   You're trying to execute a streaming query method without a
>   surrounding transaction that keeps the connection open so that the
>   Stream can actually be consumed. Make sure the code consuming the
>   stream uses @Transactional or any other way of declaring a (read-only)
>   transaction.

The `AdRepository` class follows the advice from [here](http://knes1.github.io/blog/2015/2015-10-19-streaming-mysql-results-using-java8-streams-and-spring-data.html) so the `streamAll` method looks like this:

```
@Repository
public interface AdRepository extends JpaRepository<Ad, Long> {

    @QueryHints(value = @QueryHint(name = "HINT_FETCH_SIZE", value = "" + Integer.MIN_VALUE))
    @Query(value = "SELECT href, provider FROM ad", nativeQuery = true)
    Stream<Pair<String, String>> streamAll();

    ...
}
```

I have also made sure to include the `@EnableTransactionManagement` annotation in the configuration class for the Job as told to by the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#tx-decl-explained).

```
...
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class MainTaskletsConfig {
...
```

Any idea if what I am doing is even possible and if it is what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Try encapsulating the method in a `try-with-ressources` ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45545802/spring-data-jpa-streaming-query-methods-cause-an-exception-about-transactions

Comment: Yeah I saw that answer earlier and tried wrapping the method round a `try` but it had no effect so I removed it to keep the example simple but have added back in case other people have the same thought.